# How to pad a numpy array without filling the corners?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to pad an array with a constant value like the following (actually a 3D array, but for brevity I show a 2D example here):

```
[[1,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,1]]
```

should become

```
[[0,1,1,1,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [0,1,1,1,0]]
```

Now `numpy.pad` would fill the corners (and in 3D the edges, too), which is not what I want. I could set them to zero "manually" but this gets tedious, especially in e.g. **3D**.

Is there a short and convenient way to do it?

**EDIT**
To make the 3D case more clear, here is an example:

```
[[[1]]]
```

should become

```
[[[0,0,0],
  [0,c,0],
  [0,0,0]],

 [[0,c,0],
  [c,1,c],
  [0,c,0]],

 [[0,0,0],
  [0,c,0],
  [0,0,0]]]
```

And for a padding thickness of two the example would read:

```
[[[0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]],

 [[0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]],

 [[0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [c,c,1,c,c],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0]],

 [[0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]],

 [[0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,c,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]]]
```

Comment: Fill with what? Would your array always have all ones?

Comment: With a constant value, I edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure about that second 2D slice for the 3D case? It looks identical to the first slice.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, because the second example pads by two.

Comment: I don't see how its padding for the 3D case. `1` is missing in the first two and last two slices. I can't establish how the 2D case translates to your 3D case.

Comment: 1 is in the original array of size (1,1,1). Then I pad into +-x, +-y and +-z with two `c`s every time.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to quickly follow the padding pattern in your 3d example? You padded arrays with mostly zeros with zeros and you want zeros in the comers....very confusing

Comment: The given examples are not so confusing imo. The given value is simply padded with `c` in all spatial directions. Just imagine a 2D or 3D chart, where the padding would correspond in shape to the coordinate cross.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem can actually be solved rather easily with the numpy.pad function.

According to the numpy.pad function documentation one of possible parameters to the function can be **mode : str or function
One of the following string values or a user supplied function**
(source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

This mean that all you need to do is to pass a function that checks if this is a corner and if so set the value to 0 else to 1. This of curse can be done with a bit of modification for your 3D case.

hopes that helps